# Java - Can .properties values be set statically in compiled class?

Tags: java

Can .properties values be stored statically in compiled classes?

I am updating a value in my .properties file yet the log is still showing the old value from the original .properties file.  Is this because the class file has stored the .properties values during compilation? (I do not have the original source so cannot recompile)

Comment: It seems likely that the .properties file is read at startup.  Changing it at runtime will not force a reload of properties.

Comment: What is the environment? Is it a webapp under apache/tomcat? Did you restart the application server? Maybe the application creates a singleton instance for access to the .properties file

Comment: You could decompile to code to see what it does. But its highly unlikely that properties have been compiled into the code. It is possible that the properties file is in the jar file and being read from there instead of the file system.

Answer (score 1):

Properties are not set statically in compiled class. Most likely you have old properties somewhere in classpath, or, maybe,  another property file with the same property. Try to run your application in verbose mode in order to get classpath and search in it for properties files loaded.